# how to use jQuery.ajax() in joomla

Tags: ajax, joomla3.0, virtuemart

i using virtuamart and i want to send product id in product detail to a function to store on data base 
this is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".wishlist-btn1").click(function() {
        var productid = this.id;
        var userid = jQuery('input#user_id').val();

        var data = 'userid=' + userid;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&task=productdetails.addtowish",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

and i add a function in productdetailes controllers in virtuamart
like this

```
function addtowish(){
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $name   = $jinput->get('userid');
}
```

but i don't know why in ajax return alert data , just alert html source of page !!

Add -> i think the problem is ajax can't find the function !! i wrot my function in

> productdetails

controller exactly after the line 
`class VirtueMartControllerProductdetails extends JControllerLegacy {`

Comment: what is the source that's being returned, I think that is the error html due to some php error

Comment: html source of that page !!

Comment: `http://localhost/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&task=productdetails.addtowish` if you make this request directly in browser what do you get as output?

Comment: same alert , html source page

Comment: Then Ajax will do the same thing. You need to check your PHP code

Comment: I used function addtowish(){     $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;     $name   = $jinput->get('userid'); }

Comment: Whats wrong ? On this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94787/discussion-between-erfan-pj-and-susheel-singh).

Comment: I haven't used this framework, what is your requirements

Comment: just send id to store in database